# How to select a row in jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, pos

I need to select a row in the `jtextarea`

this is my first project which I make a pos system using java,what I need to do here is that when there is a list of products in the jtextarea which are added to cart by the customer and suddenly customer wants to remove some items from the cart then my pos system should allow to select the item from the row and remove it and remove it from the mysql table too

```
textArea1.setText(item1 + "\n" + item2 + "\n" + item3 + "\n");
```

when there is a list of products in the jtextarea which are added to cart by the customer and suddenly customer whats to remove some items then my pos system should allow to select the item from the row and remove it and remove it from the mysql table too

and if you think there's a better object that jtextarea then please suggest it too .

thanks

Comment: Since you're dealing with a **list** of items perhaps consider utilizing a JList.

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of @MadProgrammer answers , (sadly i can't get the link ) i was able to produce this

```
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Utilities;

public class TextLineSelectionTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TextLineSelectionTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTextArea1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextArea1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        int pos = jTextArea1.getCaretPosition();
        try {

            int start =Utilities.getRowStart(jTextArea1, pos);
            int end =Utilities.getRowEnd(jTextArea1, pos);
            jTextArea1.setSelectionStart(start);
            jTextArea1.setSelectionEnd(end);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            //something is messed up
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                       

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TextLineSelectionTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

by using the default `Utilities` .